# Is Mayer-Vietoris sequences a sheaf theoretic result?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, homotopy-theory, sheaf-theory

I was learning Sheaf theory over past few weeks. Recently, I was told that the Mayer-Vietoris sequences in homology theory is actually a sheaf theoretic result. I was surprised by this information and, would like to know more about this connection. Can any of you explain me how we obtain Mayer-Vietoris using the sheaf condition?

I was thinking about Mayer–Vietoris sequence as the analogue of Seifert–van Kampen theorem for homology. This make me wonder whether the Seifert–van Kampen is also a sheaf theoretic result?

Comment: The Mayer-Vietoris sequence follows from the Eilenberg-Steenrod axioms (see the wiki page, for instance). In particular it applies to any generalised cohomology theory. My personal view is that while an analogy with sheaf theory might be interesting, I think it's not the `correct' way to be view singular cohomology.

Comment: Given any sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ and any cover by two open sets $U,V$ there is a long exact sequence $$...\to H^i(X,\mathcal{F})\to H^i(U,\mathcal{F})\oplus H^i(V,\mathcal{F})\to H^i(U\cap V,\mathcal{F})\to H^{i+1}(X,\mathcal{F})\to...$$ This is the Mayer-Vietoris theorem for sheaves. This is in fact a "presheaf theoretic" result since this is a particular instance of the Cech-to-derived-functor spectral sequence.

Comment: @Roland: Thank you for the comment. I have been reading about the sheaf cohomology. To be honest, I still do not understand what it mean by a cohomology with coefficients in a sheaf. In my mind, a sheaf is something like a covering space. Can you please explain this to me.

Comment: Well there is a lot of books on the subject which will do better than a comment box. It also depends on what you know and are familiar with. I assume that you are familiar with singular cohomology, are you familiar with derived functor ? with cohomology with local coefficients ? You can also read about the Mittag-Leffler problem which is a nice introduction to the $H^1$.

Comment: @Roland: I know derived functors as functors between model categories that respect to weak equivalences, but donot know much about the motivation behind (I am trying to learn category theory by my self). Also, I don't know about "local coefficients", though I know (co)homology groups with coefficients in an abelian group.